# How do I set the picture in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to set an image view to display an image here.

```
else if (n == 2) {
    gamestatus.text = @"The Card is A Two.";
    // I Need to set my imageview to a picture here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImageHere];
```

or if the imageView is already declared...

```
myImageView.image = myImageHere;
```

Edit: to answer the question about how to set to an image.

a simple way (some would argue its slightly inefficient),

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my Example Image.png"];
```